# SwiftSocket getting unknown error from UDPClient when sending

Tags: swift, macos, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to use [SwiftSockets](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) to send data from my Mac to my iPhone.

When I try the following code

```
  var socket = UDPClient(address: "192.168.1.158", port: 20777)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let res = socket.send(data: [255])
    print(res.error.debugDescription)
  }
```

I get the message `Optional(SwiftSocket.SocketError.unknownError)` and I do not receive any data from my iPhone.

What is the issue and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** If I try the hostname of my device, I get the following message

```
2018-08-27 01:28:01.893463+0100 App Name[863:10545] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
2018-08-27 01:28:02.894593+0100 App Name[863:10545] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
2018-08-27 01:28:03.894872+0100 App Name[863:10545] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
2018-08-27 01:28:04.895240+0100 App Name[863:10545] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:4 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Can someone explain why they downvoted please?

Comment: Can you try to use an hostname instead of the ip?

Comment: Yes, the hostname in the router, the same which you have in the General-Info-Name

Comment: @Kerberos see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switch from comments to the answer to add the image...

Firstly from the documentation and from the source they use the hostname instead of the IP address, it can be found under the router info clients or in the iPhone under General - Info - Name.

Then the error message seems to be a capabilities issue.

Go to capabilities and under `App Sandbox` check if it is firstly enabled and then check the `Network Incoming and Outcoming Connections` like in the image:

[image]

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Also, can you tell me where the documentations say that it uses domains only? I tried it just by updating the sandbox settings and it worked just fine! Didn't need the domain of the device in the end.